# How to use the pandas apply method in hy

Tags: pandas, dataframe, functional-programming, apply, hy

I'd like to create a new column in pandas using the .apply method where I can pass a custom function

```
df["newcol"] = df["oldcol"].apply(lambda x: x + 1)
or
df["newcol"] = df.apply(lambda row: row["oldcol"]+1)
```

How to achieve this in hy ?

so far I am able to do

```
(setv (get df "newcol") (. (get d "oldcol") apply)
```

which just sets newcol to oldcol, but couldn't figure out how to define a function to apply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend reading through [the tutorial](https://docs.hylang.org/en/stable/tutorial.html), which covers topics such as calling methods and defining anonymous functions. A literal Hy translation of

```
df["newcol"] = df.apply(lambda row: row["oldcol"]+1)
```

is

```
(setv (get df "newcol") (.apply df (fn [row] (+ (get row "oldcol") 1))))
```

Comment: Thank you. I have read the tutorial, I was confused this with the way iloc works. Your answers should be included in the tutorial.